# Definition of weak-star topology of bounded linear maps from space to dual of other space

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $X,Y$ be two Banach spaces. I'm asked to define the weak-star topology in the set of bounded linear maps from $X$ to $Y^{\prime}$, $B(X,Y^{\prime})$, where $Y^{\prime}$ is the dual space of $Y$. However, I'm not given a normed space $Z$ such that $Z^{\prime}=B(X,Y^{\prime})$. If given, the weak-star topology is the weakest topology such that
\begin{align}
B(X,Y^{\prime}) \ni M \mapsto Mz
\end{align}
is continuous for each $z \in Z$. What is $Z$? Or is there an other way to understand the question?

See below:

[image]
[image]